# couldn't find file 'jquery' in Rails project

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm working through the Agile Web Development book with Rails version 3.2.13 and Ruby 2.0.0, but I keep getting the following error when trying to access `localhost:3000`:

`Sprockets::FileNotFound in Store#index`

`couldn't find file 'jquery' (in /Users/.../app/assets/javascripts/application.js:13)`

My `application.js` file:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// ...
//    
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

In my `Gemfile`, I have `gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 2.3.0'` and have attempted many different solutions I found on the internet to no avail.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I got it to work.

1. Put `gem 'jquery-rails', "~> 2.3.0"` into Gemfile.
2. Remove Gemfile.lock by typing `rm Gemfile.lock` into the terminal.
3. Run `bundle install` from the terminal
4. Make sure `//= require jquery-ui` is in application.js

Note: If step 3 doesn't work, then run `sudo gem install jquery-rails -v 2.3.0` through the terminal.

Comment: If you're in my shoes and this didn't work: make sure you don't have the gem `jrails` installed, it will conflict with `jquery-rails` with no helpful error to tell you so.  I was upgrading to Rails 3.

Comment: Also make sure to restart rails server after this steps, only worked for me after that. Btw, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Also, if your'e using [POW](http://pow.cx/) on OS X then you might need to [restart your app](http://pow.cx/manual.html#section_2.5)

```
touch tmp/restart.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be stupid but restarting server worked for me, it recollects the libs.