# Sprockets::FileNotFound couldn't find file 'jquery'

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am new on rails and I am stuck here at this spot.

This is my application.HTML.erb The error is in the JavaScript include tag (line 6)
when I delete the line I don't get an error
I tried doing the following didn't work
[couldn't find file 'jquery' in Rails project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17285873/couldnt-find-file-jquery-in-rails-project)
I restarted my server a couple times did not help one last thing , when i open my older projects it works , but any new ones same error

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Appmind</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

**contents of application.js**

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

**gemfile contents**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.1.2'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

**trace**

```
Rails.root: C:/aptanastudio3/appmind
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___663637225_30053304'
```

any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: It took me a while but i got around it , i set my jquery-rails gem to version 3.0.4 deleted the require turbolinks in application.js then had to delete the precompresser(coffee) in post.js.coffee. I know this solution is not professional at all but there was nothing else i can find

Comment: Well, this is not a solution. Have you tried not declaring version numbers in gems? It took me a while to figure when upgrading from 4.0.0 to 4.0.2 (rails), many implicit versions in the gemfile broke.

Comment: yes the jquery-rails gem is not declared with a version i tried countless amounts of times removing the gemfile.lock and running bundle install and restarting the server ,  checked my path in sprockets for jquery and everything was fine , but still rails couldn't find it

Comment: Did you try "bundle update"?

Answer (score 3):

I found that when my gem 'jquery-rails' was wrapped in a group :assets do block, then it didn't work.  But I removed it from the block and now it does using the most modern rails.  This is different from your situation, but I think switching it around may be effective.