# Sprockets not found 'Jquery-ujs'

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My rails local server is struggling to find the jquery-ujs files. How do I fix this?

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require bootstrap
```

and finally my gemfile currently:

```
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.3.0'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

When I run the local server I get the error:

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'jquery-ujs'
```

Comment: Did you look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17285873/couldnt-find-file-jquery-in-rails-project

Comment: Ya, I followed that solution to no avail

Answer (score 0):

If you use rails 5.X you want to put in your application.js this line `//= require rails-ujs`